# textfield don't save after editing

Tags: objective-c

I have a UIViewController class on which I set a tableview and on tableview. I set tableview cell on tableview cell,  I have a text field that text field is linked with data base from where i get the values but I want to change that value I make that field editable but after editing that values should save previous values again occur please  help me

```
((UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:101]).placeholder = @"title";
    ((UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:101]).text =  arrayActivities[indexPath.row][@"title"]; //arrayActivities[indexPath.row];
    ((UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:101]).keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
```

Answer (score 0):

assign textfield delegate to self , and add this delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
        return NO;
 }
```

Comment: how to assign textfield delegate to self?? i'm new in iOS so dont mind

Comment: well, you should google these things first.
assume, your outlet for your textfield is "txtField", it will be `txtField.delegate = self`. And add UITextFieldDelegete in your .h file

Comment: this is the problem i am not able to make outlet of textfield because the textfield is on tableviewcell and the textfield that i assign an array is with TAG